# CSS: font-size and the height a font really spans

Tags: css

```
padding : 3px 3px;
height : 1em;
```

it seems actual padding-bottom is less than 3px

Comment: What you're asking is really unclear. Perhaps an example would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

True.

When you set the height property, the padding-bottom gets lost.

***Demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/a99yV/

Also, this may help you to better understand this behavior http://jsfiddle.net/a99yV/1/

Comment: thanks, Vidas. I should give more respect to the web designers.It's really complex...